# How can I display all the stories of an iteration and group them by their Epic or parent if they have one?

Tags: rally

Looking to create a custom app that shows all stories assigned to an iteration including that stories tasks, tests and defects but also grouped by Parent or Epic like the following and each item links to that work product item.  What is the best approach to group stories by parent?

Parent Story 1
 - Story 1
    - Test
    - Task
    - Defect
 - Story 2

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to query to get the stories for the iteration. If you want to allow your app's user to select the Iteration you can use the [Iteration Dropdown](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/iteration-dropdown). If you query stories using the getQueryFromSelected method on the dropdown you should have the stories that are attached to the chosen Iteration.

When fetching the stories using RallyDataSource specify Tasks, Defects and TestCases as a part of your fetch string.

If you need any other fields populated fill them in the fetch string and the dependent objects will have them filled as well. 
For example if you need their FormattedID, specifying that in your fetch string will also populate that field on the Tasks.

Once you have your data you just need to figure out how you want to display it.